# communication between activity and broadcast receiver

Tags: android

i have a broad cast receiver which needs to access data which is stored in the shared preferences of the `MainActivity.java` which is an activity of the same package.

is this code valid if it is written in the `onreceive()` method of the Broadcast receiver?

```
String s ;  
MainActivity g =new MainActivity();
s = g.getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("Key","no key");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are trying to instantiate an `Activity` via its constructor. Never do that - Activities have special initialization steps that allow them to become proper Activities (and as a result Contexts).

The [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class (which your `BroadcastReceiver` receives an instance of via the `onReceive()` method) is the the class that contains methods such as `getSharedPreferences()`.

Use that instead.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){

      String s = context.getSharedPreferences("Shared_Prefs_Name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("Key","def_value");
   }
}
```